# Flask App Heroku Deployment Single Item Issue

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment

I have a project with this structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFl8o.png)

An endpoint I have is /run-gamelogs. Essentially what it does is is trigger a web-scraper to run and then update the nba_gamelogs with the most recent gamelogs (as gamelogs change daily when new games play). The scraper takes a while to complete, so it times out on Heroku.

As a result, I have been running the endpoint on my local machine.

I also have a /run-projections endpoint which take the nba_gamelogs.json, nba_odds_data.json, and nba_projections.json to make the AI-NBA-Projections.json and I read that file in a mobile app I am creating!

Thanks so much!!!

However, when I run the endpoint to get the nba_gamelogs.json and then git add ONLY nba_gamelogs.json and push ONLY the new nba_gamelogs.json that to Heroku it reverts all of the other .json files back to when I did my initial upload instead of leaving then alone and only uploading the nba_gamelogs.json.

Any suggestions on how to upload the nba_gamelogs.json daily without touching/messing the other .json files?